# Regex match and print using awk/grep/sed/bash/vim

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file in which each line has the following structure

```
<six digit number>;; some text of arbitrary (non-zero) length<another six digit number>some other (possibly zero length) text
```

I want to extract only the pairs of six digit numbers from each line
For example, if a line contains

```
234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352some other text
```

the output would be

```
234567;;876352
```

The total number of solutions that I have tried using awk/grep/sed/bash/vim are too many to list here. Below is one of them

```
#!/bin/bash

truncate --size 0 file.out
for line in "$(cat ../allwithpins)";
do
    echo $line | 'match($0, /[0123456789]{6}/, ary) {print ary[0], ary[1]}' >> file.out
    # echo $line
    # if [[ $line =~ [0123456789]{6} ]];
    # then
    #     echo ${BASH_REMATCH[$1]}
    #     #echo ${BASH_REMATCH[$1]}
    #     #echo ${BASH_REMATCH[$2]}
    # fi;
done
```

Comment: Can the text between the digits contain digits?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R yes there can be digits and punctuations in the text

Comment: is that match supposed to be an awk command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{6};;).*([0-9]{6}).*/\1 \2/g' inputfile
234567;;876352
```

Note: If you want output not seprated by `;;` :

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{6}).*([0-9]{6}).*/\1 \2/g' inputfile
```

Here, we are here capturing the group of text in `(` and `)` and later referring them using `\1` and `\2` ...`\n`. So the contents of first ``` (``) ``` can be later reffered using `\1` and so on.

Comment: thanks for your help. But this solution also has the same problem as the other solution. It fails when the second sequence of 6 digits is followed by some other text

Comment: I replaced all sequences of 7 or more digits using regex replace in vim. Then tried your solution and it gave the perfect result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `awk`

```
awk -F"[^0-9;]" '{print $1$(NF)}'
```

- `-F"[^0-9;]"` Sets the field separator as anything other than digits, and `;`
- `print $1$(NF)` For each input line print the first and the last fields separated by the separators specified.

  `NF` is the total number of fields, so `$(NF)` will be the last field.

---

**Example**

```
$ echo "234567;; some text with any 123 number of arbitrary characters876352" | awk -F"[^0-9;]" '{print $1$(NF)}'
234567;;876352
```

---

**Edit**

In case you want to add in more checks to the number of digits, etc, the regex comparisons can help you.

**Example**

```
$ awk -F"[^0-9;]" '$1 ~ /[0-9]{6};;/ && $0 ~ /[^0-9][0-9]{6}$/{print $1$(NF)}' file
234567;;876352
234567;;876352

$ cat file
234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352
234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352iaasdfadf
234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352
234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters8763
234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352iaasdfadf0987654321
```

- `$1 ~ /[0-9]{6};;/`  Checks if the first field contain 6 digits followed by `;;`
- `$0 ~ /[^0-9][0-9]{6}$` Checks if the input line ends with 6 digits. `[^0-9]` Checks if the 6 digits are not preceded by another digit.

Comment: thanks. This solution works except in the case when the second sequence of 6 digits is followed by some other text. It may not always be the last field, as mentioned in the question. Also, using this solution inside the script originally posted, generates an output file with only one line.

Comment: @sid-m If you want to have more checks on the input lines you can add checks before the `{print }`. I have added an edit. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks. your help is greatly appreciated. This solution almost worked.
But it turned out that some line happened to contain a ten digit sequence after the second 6 digit sequence like
`234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352iaasdfadf0987654321` and the command ended up printing the 10 digit sequence instead

Comment: @sid-m oops that was a mistake from my end. Have corrected it. Will add an explanation to what it does

Comment: thanks, I am sorry for constantly nagging. May be I am having hard time explaining my requirement clearly. But the six digit sequence need to be extracted even if it is not at the end of the line. There may be other characters following it. any way this is very close so upvoted :)

Comment: @sid-m So are you are trying to say that the last occurring sequence of digits should be only 6 in length. And that if the last sequence is more that 6 digits nothing should be returned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129331/discussion-between-sid-m-and-nu11p01n73r).

Answer (score 0):

With sed, to remove all characters except digits and semi-colons:

```
sed 's/[^0-9;]//g' <<< "234567;; some text with any number of arbitrary characters876352some other text"
234567;;876352
```